# appending text to each alt tag jquery

Tags: jquery, image, attributes, alt

I am attempting to create a function using jQuery that appends a copyright message to the end of all alt tags. So `<img src="image.jpg" alt="this is alt text">` would end up `<img src="image.jpg" alt="this is alt text - Copyright (c) John Doe">`.

This is the function I created but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        $img.attr("alt").append(" - Copyright (c) John Doe");
    });
});
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ysJMN/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('alt',$(this).attr('alt')+" - Copyright (c) John Doe");
    });
});
```

`$(this)` refers to the current image in each loop.

`$(this).attr('alt')` get's the current attribute `alt`

`$(this).attr('alt','value')` this is how you assign `value` to the `alt` attribute

`$(this).attr('alt',$(this).attr('alt')+" - Copyright (c) John Doe");` so code here replace the `current` with  `current` + `" - Copyright (c) John Doe"`

Errors in your code

`$img` is not defined.

`append` deals with adding `html content`s to the element not the `attribute`

Comment: Somebody has marked this post as low quality, most likely because you didn't explain your answer. While I agree it's low quality, it's "SO-grade." However, I do encourage you to actually answer the question in a way that the OP will not have to come back with the same issue as opposed to just giving code out like it's a free-sample fair.

Comment: @Jeremy it is very simple code easy to understand i don't think any explanation needed and that Somebody is jealous of my code.

Comment: I guess that's where you're wrong, especially for beginners - something SO is filled with.

Comment: @Jeremy explained everything

Comment: Yup I'm a beginner, and I appreciate the explanation. So thanks @Tushar Gupta. This version worked.

Comment: I've given you a +1 for updating your post. Please make sure to do this in the future, also. No problem @semidivine

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("alt",function(i,alt){
             return alt + " - Copyright (c) John Doe";
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would only use `append` to add something to an HTML element. Not an attribute. You can do this to append to an attribute. There's no reason for the `each` using this method.

```
$('img').attr('alt', function( idx, originalAlt ){
  return originalAlt + ' - Copyright (c) John Doe'
});
```